# Fix redirect after rewrite in Apache web server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have pages created dynamically with a Single Page Application with URLs like https://oga.org.uk/boat_register/boat/?oga_no=3511.

I've got the following .htaccess file installed in /boat_register:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /boat_register/

RewriteRule ^boat/([0-9]+)/?$ /boat_register/boat?oga_no=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This makes path based URLs work so boats can be accessed by either https://oga.org.uk/boat_register/boat/?oga_no=3511 or https://oga.org.uk/boat_register/boat/3511.

I tried to get the https://oga.org.uk/boat_register/boat/3511 URL to be the one shown in the URL bar but none of the recipes I found worked for me. It still 301 redirects to the original URL. What can I do to the .htaccess file and/or get changes made to the core Apache configuration to make it look like the path based URLs are the real ones?

This is the server response to the path based request:

```
> GET /boat_register/boat/3511 HTTP/2
> Host: oga.org.uk
> User-Agent: curl/8.1.2
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/2 301 
< content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< server: Apache
< location: http://oga.org.uk/boat_register/boat/?oga_no=3511
< x-origin-cache-status: HIT
< date: Sat, 16 Sep 2023 06:21:46 GMT
< x-via: LHR2
< x-cdn-node-is-at-origin: 1
< x-cdn-cache-status: HIT
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://oga.org.uk/boat_register/boat/?oga_no=3511">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: That alone should not redirect. You have more (relevant to URL rewriting) in your .htaccess than just those lines?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of - the file I've listed is what is installed as far as I know. (sorry for only just noticing your comment).